# Search Data not working Angular NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular

i am created the search part using angular and node js. i have tested through the postman it is working fine. when connect with frond end anqular application is it not working error displayed

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

what i tried so far i attached below please check.
i tried on the url `http://localhost:9001/user/findOne?first_name=kobinath`
this is working well on postman but tested through the anqular didn't work. i attached the code what i tried so far.

employee.component.ts

```
 search()
  {
    let name= {
      "first_name" : this.first_name
     
    };

    this.http.post("http://localhost:9001/user/findOne",name).subscribe((resultData: any)=>
    {
        console.log(resultData);
       
    });

  }
```

employee.component.html

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">

  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" (click)="search()" >Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I noticed: With Postman you send `first_name` as a query parameter, but in your Angular-code you attach it to the request-body.

To achieve the equivalent of what you do in Postman, you could use the following code:

```
search(firstName: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('first_name', firstName);
    const body = {
        first_name : firstName
    };

    this.http.post("http://localhost:9001/user/findOne", body, { params: params })
        .subscribe((resultData: any)=>
        {
            console.log(resultData);            
        });
}
```

Btw: Why don't you use **GET** instead of POST?

Comment: if i get the post request it is not working